# Conditional Sentence Using IF and HAD

Tags: conditional-constructions

What is use Diffrence between below two conditional Sentence.

Had I been present at the Creation, I would have given some useful hints for the better ordering of the universe.

And

If i had present at the creation, i would have given som useful hints for the better ordering of the Universe.

When to start conditional sentence useing if and Had.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference in meaning. The first structure...

> Had I been present *[etc.]*

...will probably seem more formal to most audiences, although that might just be because it's less common. The second structure...

> If I had been present *[etc.]*

...is more common, and so will probably seem less formal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning, context or implication. Either could be phrased with a certain tone to make a certain point.

Your second sentence is missing "been" though. It should be: "If I had been present at the Creation, I would have given some useful hints for the better ordering of the universe."

This is the indicative form. Technically speaking, I think you should use the subjunctive form here since you're speculating about something that can't/won't happen: "Were I present at..." or "If I were present at..."